# how to force compilation of Boost to use -fPIC

Tags: c++, boost

The team on which I work produces a shared library for use in Python.  This library is entirely C++ and we use Boost to expose to python.  Because we cannot guarantee that our clients have the Boost libraries installed, we pull in the functionality needed from Boost to the shared object file statically.  The final stage in compilation will look familiar to many

```
g++ -o <output> <objects> -Wl,-Bstatic -lboost_python -lboost_regex ... -Wl,-Bdynamic -shared <other_opts>
```

We've traditionally used our own build of Boost: 1.47.  This version is now quite old and so we wish to update.  However, oddly, when I install the necessary objects using yum on my CentOS 7 system, I get the following error from gcc:

```
relocation R_X86_64_32 against '.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

Well, I thought I'd simply download the latest boost (CentOS 7 installs Boost 1.53) and do my own build.  This, after all, has always worked for us.  I follow the [instructions here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#prepare-to-use-a-boost-library-binary) but I got the same error.  How do I force the use of -fPIC for even the static libraries that it builds?

Comment: Are you sure that gcc (or the executable at runtime) is finding the custom-built Boost libraries?  You can modify the library search directories using `-L` in gcc or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` at runtime.

Comment: You can direct boost build to use compiler flags using `cxxflags="-fPIC"`.  There is a similar variable named `linkflags`.  See boost build documentation at http://www.boost.org/build/doc/html/bbv2/overview/invocation.html

Comment: @NicholasM yes, I am sure my libraries were being used by ld.  I am using the -L option to ld to enforce this.  Thank you very much for that link.  The link I was using didn't mention this.

Comment: _"Because we cannot guarantee that our clients have the Boost libraries installed"_ Surely this is why we publish dependencies? Name them in your RPM's .spec file?

Comment: @lightnessracesinorbit. That's precisely what I finally decided to do.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I believe boost automatically uses `-fPIC` when compiling a shared library (.so file), but the below command uses `-fPIC` when compiling a static library (.a file) too.

This worked for me on boost 1.46.1:

```
sudo ./bjam cxxflags=-fPIC cflags=-fPIC -a ... install
```

The `...` is where you add additional flags like `threading=multi` or `--layout=tagged`, and optionally the list of projects to build (for example: `--with-regex`).

*Note: using both `cflags` and `cxxflags` is unnecessary, only one is needed. See comments below.*

**Reference links:**

- https://cmake.org/Wiki/TubeTK/Build_Instructions#Boost_.28optional.29
- http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2010/07/60682.php

Comment: Boost 1.61.0: `cflags` seems redundant. Also `sudo` should be redundant for local (i.e. not system-wide) installation .

Comment: @smbear I agree `cflags` probably is redundant. I wasn't sure if I needed it, but it didn't seem to hurt.

Comment: cxxflags is C++ and cflags both C and C++. So cxxflags is technically the redundant one as it is strictly implied, but then Boost is C++ so they're just the same.

Answer (score 4):

Just for convenience, I combined previous answer and comments to it:

```
sudo ./bjam cxxflags=-fPIC -a --with-system install
```

--with-system is not necessary, but it's a place where you can add other boost compile options

It works for me at CentOS 7 with boost 1.67

Comment: Hello Nikolay, This step has to be one after executing bootstrap.sh ? right ?

Comment: @atari83 As far as I remember - yes

Answer (score 3):

Another solution:

```
./bootstrap.sh
./b2 cxxflags=-fPIC cflags=-fPIC
```