# Cannot link boost library to shared library

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, boost

Upon linking the boost 1.63.0 library `libboost_regex-mt.a` to a shared library I am getting the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libboost_regex-mt.a(instances.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libboost_regex-mt.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
```

I actually have compiled boost with -fPIC by using the following command (also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27848105/how-to-force-compilation-of-boost-to-use-fpic)):

```
./bjam '-sBUILD=<cxxflags>-fPIC <linkflags>-fPIC' --without-mpi --without-python --without-iostreams --layout=tagged link=shared,static
```

When doing a bjam debug build, it seems that bjam only seems to honor the `-fPIC` for some source files, other files (including `instances.cpp` from the regex library) are compiled without it:

```
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/regex/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/threading-multi/instances.o

    "g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -pedantic -pthread -m64  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/regex/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/threading-multi/instances.o" "libs/regex/build/../src/instances.cpp"
```

How do I force bjam to use the `-fPIC` flag for all files?

Answer (score 1):

Build boost 1.63, shared libraries :

```
./b2 --without-mpi --without-python --without-iostreams --layout=tagged link=shared runtime-link=shared link=static install
```

threading=multi :

```
./b2 --without-mpi --without-python --without-iostreams --layout=tagged threading=multi link=shared runtime-link=shared link=static install
```

---

"regex" result : `ls *regex*`

```
libboost_regex.a
libboost_regex-mt.a
libboost_regex-mt.so@
libboost_regex-mt.so.1.63.0*
libboost_regex.so@
libboost_regex.so.1.63.0*
```

Comment: The threading_multi command still builds without -fPIC, e.g. `"g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -pedantic -pthread -m64  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/regex/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/threading-multi/instances.o" "libs/regex/build/../src/instances.cpp"`