# Static link boost library with shared library in CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, static-libraries

I am trying to build an executable, and to change the link for boost library to static. The codes that I am trying to compile is [here](https://bitbucket.org/dmartinezm/rex-d/src).

I am using Xubuntu 14.04, cmake 3.5.1, boost 1.54.

The error I got is:

```
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/librexd.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.a(error_code.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
```

Things I have done:
Set boost library to static link in CMakeLists.txt (an example):

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost 1.46.0 COMPONENTS system regex program_options thread filesystem REQUIRED)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(rexd ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

There are alot of CMakeLists.txt, so I did the above for 3 of them that uses Boost.

Next, I set the compiler flag to -fPIC for CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS and CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG, for example:

```
SET (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS                "-D_REENTRANT -fpic")
SET (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG          "-g -Wall -fpic")
```

Again, I did it for all CMakeLists that have CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS and CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG variables.

Lastly, I recompile boost with -fPIC option. I downloaded boost.tar.gz from sourceforge, extract it, and ran this:

```
bjam clean
bjam -d+2 link=static cxxflags="-fPIC" install
```

However, this does not seem to change anything. the date modification for libboost_system.a is dated a few years ago.

I have tried to tinker with add_library, making this static

```
ADD_LIBRARY(rexd STATIC ${sources_symbolic} ${sources_parsers} ${sources_lfit} ${sources_teacher} ${sources_rexd} ${sources_ippc_planner})
```

I got this error instead where it couldn't find a header .h:

```
No such file or directory
```

How should I proceed? I apologize if this question is too specific for my use case, but I can't find any other answers out there that I haven't tried.

Comment: What version of CMake and Boost are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to force compilation of Boost to use -fPIC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27848105/how-to-force-compilation-of-boost-to-use-fpic)

Comment: @hacksalot cmake 3.5.1, boost 1.54. although the code says boost 1.46, I have successfully build and used it with boost 1.54.

Comment: @Mathieu I have read that link you posted before posting this question. I don't see how it could solve my problem. could you elaborate?

Comment: Errors like this are almost always indicative of a configuration error somewhere in the pipeline. That is, when configured and installed properly, Boost + CMake should *just work*. You shouldn't need to dig down into CMake files except possibly your own, if they don't use standard idioms. When I run into errors like this, I check my versions, verify my file hierarchies, etc. Hand-tweaking to *force* Boost to compile or link correctly is brittle and a little scary. =)

Comment: @hacksalot well, I don't know how to check configuration error, that seems pretty broad. where should I start?

Comment: Can you produce other Boost builds on your toolchain? Everything works except in this case?

Comment: @hacksalot do you mean other builds with static link? this is the first time I am trying it. boost works fine when linked dynamically. the problem right now is to link it statically.

Comment: `bjam -d+2 link=static cxxflags="-fPIC" install` is indeed what you needed to do, but you needed to do it as `sudo`. If you didn't, it failed, and you would not necessarily have noticed. Even if it succeeded it would not change the modification date of `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.a` because the new installation will be under `/usr/local/lib`.

Comment: @MikeKinghan yes, thank you. I just figured that out. I used this instead:    `sudo ./b2 link=static,shared --with=all`  Also, the new installation is as you said, in /usr/local/lib. this time, I got a new error that libthread.a is not found. somehow, this library cannot be installed    `skipped libboost_thread.a for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/thread/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/threading-multi>`

Comment: ok, I got it fixed. it was a really silly mistake. the library rex-d has to be set to STATIC which lead to a missing header...because the header file (my own code that is not in the original repository) resides in the build folder that was deleted. so what I did was to change only ONE CMakeLists.txt to set boost library to static, change some libraries to static, and make. No fPIC, no recompiling of boost required. lastly, in case anyone needs this, if running the executable gives an error of missing shared library, set your LD_LIBRARY_PATH.